# How to display list of connections in a networkx graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I currently have the following code for my networkx weighted graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge("sam", "ben", weight=0.6)
G.add_edge("sam", "ted", weight=0.2)
G.add_edge("ted", "may", weight=0.1)
G.add_edge("ted", "chris", weight=0.7)
G.add_edge("ted", "nick", weight=0.9)
G.add_edge("sam", "may", weight=0.3)

elarge = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d["weight"] > 0.5]
esmall = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d["weight"] <= 0.5]

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)  # positions for all nodes

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=700)

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=elarge, width=6)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(
    G, pos, edgelist=esmall, width=6, alpha=0.5, edge_color="b", style="dashed"
)

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=20, font_family="sans-serif")

plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Which gives the following output:
[image]

I've been searching, but cannot find a way to hover over a node and list all its connections. For example: if I hovered over node A I would know that it is connected to B, C, and D and their respective weights. I saw [this](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/graph.html#interaction-policies) and [this](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html?highlight=hover#custom-tooltip) hover feature on Bokeh.
Any ideas on how I could embed that into my code? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see tutorials [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/users/event_handling.html). Here are solutions according to your data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge("a", "b", weight=0.6)
G.add_edge("a", "c", weight=0.2)
G.add_edge("c", "d", weight=0.1)
G.add_edge("c", "e", weight=0.7)
G.add_edge("c", "f", weight=0.9)
G.add_edge("a", "d", weight=0.3)

elarge = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d["weight"] > 0.5]
esmall = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d["weight"] <= 0.5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)  # positions for all nodes
names = np.array(list("abcdef"))

# nodes
# you have to return sc to for interaction to work
sc = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=700)

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=elarge, width=6)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(
    G, pos, edgelist=esmall, width=6, alpha=0.5, edge_color="b", style="dashed"
)

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=20, font_family="sans-serif")

annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)

def update_annot(ind):

    pos = sc.get_offsets()[ind["ind"][0]]
    annot.xy = pos
    es = [e for e in G[names[ind["ind"]][0]]]
    text = "{}".format(es)
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.4)


def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        cont, ind = sc.contains(event)
        if cont:
            update_annot(ind)
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)
```

**Key points**:

- return scatter points (`PathCollection`) for interaction to work.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm very new to python, so Im sorry for asking a stupid question but where would the return sc go?

Comment: inside `update_annot()`, if it solves your issue, pls accept it.

Comment: I put return sc under update_annot() but no graph pops up.

Comment: Sorry! it's working now, just realized you missed the plt.show() at the end, which is why it wasn't working. thank you :)

Comment: pls copy paste my code, it should work fine. Not returning sc in `update_annot`, return sc from `nx.draw_networkx_nodes`, whcih I have did it for you..

Comment: Try and explore abit more by yourself, and read carefully about the link I posted.

Comment: do you also update `names` correctly? code should be no problems. You have to make all stuff consistent.

Comment: hi, sorry for troubling you again! but if my names are more than a letter (unlike the example above) ex. sam, how would I update that? just names = np.array(["sam", "..."])? Because when I do this I get this error: index 15 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: happens in this line? `es = [e for e in G[names[ind["ind"]][0]]]`?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because I have different strings in the list and not one "abcde" like in the example, but how would I change the es line to fit this?

Comment: it's and index error, try to print G[names[ind["ind"]][0]]] or names[...]. pls locate the error first

Comment: also why not update your example code using what your have modified...

Comment: when I print "es" and "names" the output is exactly the same list of names. I only changed a, b, c, d, e, f to real life names